# Apache Mahout Clustering Example for Windows Along with System requirements

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout

I am new in Apache Mahout and hadoop. I am using windows 8. i would like to develop a mahout clustering example. Can anybody please help me with  the step by step process to do this example.

Comment: Don't use Mahout on *single* systems. It *costs* a lot of overhead. Either use it on a *real cluster*, or use a single-host software like ELKI, which will be 10x faster than Mahout.

Comment: Anony-Mousse, For testing and learning purpose what do i do?
Can you just give what ever needed for this and links

Comment: If you don't have a real cluster, you won't be able to really learn and test this. Because in reality, it will be *very* different. Because you don't apply it to big data on your test setup anyway.

Comment: So either, A) get big data, B) get a cluster. Or A) get small data, and B) use small data tools. There is no use in mixing these two paths up, because you only waste a lot of time, to then find out in the end that big data != small data, even if you used a big data tool on small data.